# Can a Java Long type be a fraction?

Tags: java

Can a Java Long type be a fraction?

```
long longValue = 0.2;
```

I've tried to Google and found their minimum and maximum values but I couldn't determine whether that included fractional or whole values.

> ```
> static long   MAX_VALUE
> ```
>
> A constant holding the maximum value a long can have, 2<sup>63</sup>-1.
>
> ```
> static long   MIN_VALUE
> ```
>
> A constant holding the minimum value a long can have, -2<sup>63</sup>.

Comment: Print `longValue` and look?

Comment: No it can't. A `long` is a 64 bit integer. Try `float` or `double`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to definition of `long` from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

> long: The long data type is a 64-bit two's complement integer. The
>   signed long has a minimum value of -2<sup>63</sup> and a maximum value of 2<sup>63</sup>-1.
>   In Java SE 8 and later, you can use the long data type to represent an
>   unsigned 64-bit long, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum
>   value of 2<sup>64</sup>-1. Use this data type when you need a range of values
>   wider than those provided by int.

In addition, here's an extract for `long` from full Java SE 8 specification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html (4.2.1)

> The values of the integral types are integers in the following ranges:
>   For long, from -9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807, inclusive

So, no. Neither Java `long` primitive type nor `Long` class can hold a fraction